# Which sub-field of psychology is the best for a research focus on complex trauma?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, developmental-psychology, clinical-psychology, trauma

Which sub-field of psychology is the best option for a research focus on complex trauma (CPTSD)? I want to apply for a PhD in psychology. I like research, but like clinical works too. However, my main motivation is to study complex trauma. Which field would be the best suit for me: Clinical? Developmental? Social? Or cognitive psychology?

Or maybe some health sub-field such as Public Health?

Comment: This sounds opinion-based to me - how would we know what's best for you? This makes it off-topic here.